# How do you stop event propagation when clicking a scrollbar in IE10+

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, scrollbar, event-propagation

I have a Leaflet map positioned in a div, and a layer list on top of it. The layer list is often long, and a scrollbar is shown due to a CSS property of `overflow:scrollbar` being set.

If you click anywhere but on the scrollbar drag is not propagated to the map below however if you click and drag the scrollbar it is propagated to the map and it starts being dragged.

This only applies to IE10+ it works as expected in Firefox, Chrome etc.

How do I prevent this behavior?

Comment: Catch your event and tell it to stop, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Is it possible to catch a click event on a scrollbar? my layerlist contains clickable element, and I do not want to stop those events.

Comment: No. Scope of JS is till window and anything outside window cannot be captured. But if you want to stop scroll, you can check for window.scroll event and process accordingly

Comment: But the scrollbar is inline on a div - does that count as outside the window?

Comment: Also it is not the scroll event - it is the click event on the scrollbar that triggers drag on the underlying layer

Comment: My apologies! Also I dont know if this helps but check following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816013/is-it-possible-to-capture-mouse-events-on-a-scroll-bar-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I should have read more about Leaflet. I found that Leaflet hijacks all event handling and implements its own event model. The normal stopPropagation, window.event.cancelBubble or what have you won't work.

You have to use Leaflet's own handler:

```
L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(leafletMenu);
```

The reason for this is that my menu element was created as a Leaflet control:

```
leafletMenu = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'niras-map-menu');
```